# .htaccess issue with url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

This url format https://portal.com/pages does not work but this https://portal.com/index.php/pages works.

I want to be able to remove the index.php from the url.

My root .htaccess file is

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  # First rewrite to HTTPS:
  # Don't put www. here. If it is already there it will be included, if not
  # the subsequent rule will catch it.
  # RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
  # RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]
  RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
  
</IfModule>
```

While public folder .htaccess file is

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options -Multiviews
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following rules htaccess file. Make sure your index.php is present inside public folder. Please make sure to clear browser cache before testing your URLs.

root htaccess rules file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Public folder inside htaccess Rules file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteOptions InheritBefore
  Options -Multiviews
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

***Fixes done in OP's attempt:***

- root htaccess Rules file didn't have https apply rule, so have added it.
- Made public applying rule for all kind of urls.
- Then in public folder rules file added InheritBefore option to make sure root's file is being inherited to public folder's htaccess rules file.

Comment: I have followed instructions but same issue still.

This works fine in a linux server but I just migrated to ubuntu hence the issue surfaced.

Comment: @BerniceGolomo, ok so you mean these Rules posted by me here worked on 1 server and didn't work on another?

Comment: No. The initial rules I posted works on linux but not on ubuntu,

I have also tried your rules on ubuntu an its still same issue.

Comment: @BerniceGolomo, ok could you please put a line like `--------` in both of htaccess files and hit like `http://localhost:80/` AND `http://localhost:80/non-existing-page` urls and see if you get 500 internal error. If you get 500 internal error means its enabled else its not, let me know how it goes.

Comment: Sorry I am lost

Comment: @BerniceGolomo, Please place a simple test line like: `---------` in both htaccess and hit any url and let me know if you get 500 internal error or not?

Comment: Ok so I added --------- at the begining of both .htaccess files and tried accessing url but nothing happened

Comment: @BerniceGolomo, if you are NOT getting 500 internal error then it means your htaccess files are NOT enabled.

Comment: @BerniceGolomo, Please check url https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-rewrite-urls-with-mod_rewrite-for-apache-on-ubuntu-18-04 to enable your htaccess files and then try my rules and let me know how it goes.

Comment: @BerniceGolomo, could you please do let me know if provided rules and above link for Ubuntu htaccess has worked for you?

Comment: I got 500 internal server error. After I enabled .htacess file, my website was accessible. Thanks